# How to get the result with a single cte?

Tags: sql, hive

I have 4 queries, each one starts with a CTE:

```
with stg as
(
    select columns
    from stage
    where conditions1
)
```

After this the differences begin. In first case, I need to join with 2 tables on some conditions

```
select cols
from stg
inner join table1 on cond2
inner join table2 on cond3
where con4
```

In second. I need to join to table2, but on different conditions

```
select cols
from stg
inner join table2 on cond5
where cond6
```

In the third, I simply need all columns that fit cond7

```
select cols
from stg
where cond7
```

And in the fourth, again different table and cond

```
select cols
from stg
left join table3 on cond8
where cond9
```

The thing is, after every query I need to insert changed data back. It's basically

```
insert into table stage
    select *
    from query(1-4)
```

So I can't chain this CTEs. And after every insert the cte returns less rows. For example

First time it will return 100 rows, second 85 and so on. What I want is way to use the CTE just once. At first I thought about changing all join to left join, adding them to the CTE itself and creating a flag of sorts

```
with stg as
(
    select 
        cols,
        table1.col as flag1,
        table2.col as flag2,
        table3.col as flag3
    from 
        stage
    left join 
        table1 on cond
    left join 
        table2 on cond
    left join 
        table3 on cond
    where 
        many conditions
)
```

But this turned very messy, very quickly and didn't even work right. Then I though about actually chaining it and then unioning 4 CTEs to get rid if doubles if they exist. But that too doesn't seem like a smart choice. Are there any other variants?

Comment: Voted to close. This question is a mess. What does the use of CTE got to do with duplicates in your results? wrap it up into a sub-query and use distinct

Comment: Your examples are too abstract and do not shed much light on your problem. More realistic queries with sample data would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If cols is the same for all the 4 queries you can use

```
Q1
union all
Q2
union all
Q3
union all
Q4
```

UPDATE: to remove duplicates use `union` instead of `union all`

UPDATE2: If `union all` is not supported we can use distinct + subquery

```
select distinct *
from (Q1
      union all
      Q2
      union all
      Q3
      union all
      Q4) sub
```

Comment: @This will return a lot of doubles.

Comment: The answer updated

Comment: Just for the sake of being complete: Hive versions prior to 1.2.0 only support UNION ALL

Comment: Updated the answer once more

Answer (score 0):

You can have multple cte's separetad with a comma

```
WITH cte1 AS (SELECT ... FROM ...),
     cte2 AS (SELECT ... FROM cte1 INNER JOIN ...),
     cte3 AS (SELECT ... FROM cte2 INNER JOIN ...)

SELECT * FROM cte3
```

Comment: I know, but how will this help me? The conditions are different and even contradictory. So cte to will return what I need for first query, but in cte3 there will be one condition that will just filter all rows from cte2 and vice versa. Cte 3 returns rows I need but, another will filter all pr half of them.